# Adding (and then removing) a span to a div causes Javascript to not fire when img in the same div is clicked. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm building a chess app as a summer project and it works by submitting jQuery requests when pieces or squares are clicked. When a piece is clicked the request will return the valid squares for that piece to move to and then it adds a dot on that square to indicate that it can be moved there (it removes the dot after a square or other piece is clicked). The problem is that if there is already a piece on that square, the dot is added and then when it is removed, when the piece is clicked it no longer fires the Javascript. When I refresh the page it works fine again. How can I fix this so that even when a dot is added and then removed, clicking the piece will fire the js correctly?

This is the js code that runs when a piece is clicked:

```
$("img.piece").on("click", function(){
if (parent != undefined && parent.attr("class")=="light_square"){
    parent.css("background-color","WhiteSmoke");
    $(".dot").remove();
} else if (parent != undefined && parent.attr("class")=="dark_square") {
    parent.css("background-color","Sienna");
    $(".dot").remove();
}
parent = $(this).parent();
sq_one = $(this).attr("id").slice(5,10);
parent.css("background-color", "Gold");
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    type:'POST',
    url:"/moves",
    data:JSON.stringify({'sq_one':sq_one}),
    success: function(response) {
        for (x in response) {
            var id = "square("+response[x]+")";
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += ("<span class=\"dot\"></span>");
        }
    }
    });
});
```

`$(".dot").remove();` is also used when a square is clicked.

The CSS for dots, squares, and pieces is as follows:

```
.dark_square {
    background-color: Sienna;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.piece {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
}
```

Finally I'm using a table to do the board and the html looks like this:

```
<td id="square({{ 8-x }},{{ y+1 }})" class="light_square">
    <img id="piece({{ 8-x }},{{ y+1 }})" class="piece" src="/static/images/{{ img_dict[(8-x,y+1)] }}">
</td>
```

Comment: Try using minimal & reproducable code snippets. You'll probably figure out the problem yourself while creating such a snippet, and if not, you'll cater many more responses from others.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are happy to help but you need to help us first by trying to scale down your code to remove anything not relevant to the specific issue. When it comes to troubleshooting an issue like this in the page UI your server code is completely useless to us also. Take a few minutes to read through [mcve]. Then you can edit the question at any time to improve or clarify.

Comment: My guess is you need to use **event delegation**. [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried to scale down my code.